# How to include CSS files of javafx project in gradle assemble?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I have a javafx project including css files. I want them directly in the main java src:

```
src/main/java/Foo.java
src/main/java/Foo.css
```

When I now use my gradle script to build a fat jar, it does not include the css files and running the jar ends up in a npe.

My gradle script looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

jar {
  manifest { 
    attributes "Main-Class": "foo.Main"
  }
  from {
    configurations.compile.collect {
      it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
    }
    configurations.runtime.collect {
      it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
    }
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.sarxos:webcam-capture:0.3.10'
}
```

What can I do to get a runnable jar file from gradle?
I tried already to explicitly include the css files - it did not work / I did it wrong ...

Comment: Maybe put the CSS files under `src/main/resources`? They will be added automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change your resource files to a resource directory, then you can use:

```
jar {
  manifest { 
    attributes "Main-Class": "foo.Main"
  }
  from {
    configurations.compile.collect {
      it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
    }
    configurations.runtime.collect {
      it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
    }
  }

  from('src/main/java') {
     include '**/*.css'
  }

}
```